# how to pass extra input parameter in tensorflow in iOS?

Tags: ios, opencv, tensorflow

I am sending parameter to tensorflow as following:

```
 std::string input_layer = "input_node";
    std::string output_layer = "output_node";
    std::string dropout_layer = "keep_prob"; //--- extra parameter

    Status run_status = session->Run({{input_layer, resized_tensor}},
                                       {output_layer}, {}, &outputs);
      if (!run_status.ok()) {
        LOG(ERROR) << "Running model failed: " << run_status;
        return -1;
      }
```

I tried as

```
 tensorflow::Status run_status = session->Run({{input_layer,dropout_layer, image_tensor}},{output_layer},{}, &outputs);
```

but it is not accepting extra parameter 
How can i send extra input parameter ?

Comment: So you tried `{output_layer, dropout_layer}` as output tensors and it didn't work? What is the error message? To be clear, you want to get the tensor out of the `dropout_layer`?